# Definition of an $f$-speedup

Tags: complexity-theory

My question is motivated by [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26320/a-rigorous-definition-for-an-exponential-quantum-advantage/26417?noredirect=1#comment34512_26417) one

I am looking for a reference in which the definition of an $f$-speedup is provided.

Let's assume that we have an algorithmic problem to solve. This problem takes an integer $n$ as input to describe it and provides as output a bit string providing the answer we are expecting.

Then, I have two algorithms, $C$ and $Q$ to solve the task. The first one requires $C(n)$ operations while the second one requires $Q(n)$ operations.

What are the conditions that $C(n)$ and $Q(n)$ have to satisfy in order to say that the algorithm $Q$ has an $f$-speedup over the algorithm $C$.

A naïve definition would be to ask, where $\alpha$ is some constant:

$$\frac{C(n)}{Q(n)}=\Omega(f(Poly(n)))$$

With this definition, it means that I have to do "at least" $f(Poly(n))$ more operations (where $Poly(n)$ is some polynome in $n$) with the algorithm $C$ compared to the algorithm $Q$. For instance, if $f=\exp$, it would mean that the algorithm $C$ is $\exp(Poly(n))$ times longer than $Q$, hence I have an exponential speedup.

Note that in this example for $C(n)=e^{n}$ and $Q(n)=e^{0.99 n}$, we would still say that $Q$ has an exponential speedup as $C(n)/Q(n)=e^{0.001n}$

Another definition could say, for $f$ bijective:

$$C(n)=f(\Omega(Poly(Q(n)))) \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(C(n))=\Omega(Poly(Q(n)))$$

This for for instance used [here](https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org/) for $f(n)=2^n$ to define a superpolynomial speedup.

Overall: **what is the definition used by the community to define an $f$-speedup**, and **what is its motivation?** If it doesn't agree with one of my definitions here I would like to understand what is "bad" in my proposals.

Comment: You say an instance of your problem is described by an integer n. An integer n can be stored in log n bits. So your problem size is only log n. I would change n to mean "the size of the instance of the problem".

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no such notion in the parallel computing community. The closest definition that I can think of is the following, that you will find in the book "Introduction to Parallel Algorithms" by C. Xavier and S. S. Iyengar (beware: its not actually used in practice):

Asymptotic Real Speedup

Let $S(n)$ be the asymptotic complexity of the best sequential algorithm for the problem and let $P(n)$ be the asymptotic complexity of the parallel algorithm under the assumption that the parallel computer has available to it as many processors as it can gainfully use. The asymptotic real speedup $ARS(n)$ is $$ARS(n) = \frac{S(n)}{P(n)}$$.

One can also define Asymptotic Relative Speedup: this differs from asymptotic real speedup, in that for the sequential complexity we use the asymptotic time complexity of the parallel algorithm when run on a single processor.

Comment: The difference is important when the best parallel algorithm takes more operations than the best non-parallel algorithm, which is not uncommon. For example, you might need n operations on a single processor, and n + k^3 with k processors, making the time n vs. n/k + k^2. That's also  situation where using unlimited resources would actually not be beneficial; some value k close to n^(1/3) would be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

The *speedup* is the ratio of the running times of two "programs", in the same conditions. This follows a statistical distribution that is a function of the input size, which you can characterize with asymptotic $O$ and $\Omega$ bounds, as usual.

E.g. the speedup of QuickSort over InsertionSort is $\Omega(1)$ and $O\left(\dfrac n{\log n}\right)$.